# GitHub Actions' default "Post Check out Git repository" job: What does it do?

Tags: git, github, github-actions

My GitHub Actions all have the same penultimate step added by default:

```
Post Check out Git repository
--- 
Post job cleanup.
$> /usr/bin/git version
git version 2.32.0
$> /usr/bin/git config --local --name-only --get-regexp core\.sshCommand
$> /usr/bin/git submodule foreach --recursive git config --local --name-only --get-regexp 'core\.sshCommand' && git config --local --unset-all 'core.sshCommand' || :
$> /usr/bin/git config --local --name-only --get-regexp http\.https\:\/\/github\.com\/\.extraheader
http.https://github.com/.extraheader
$> /usr/bin/git config --local --unset-all http.https://github.com/.extraheader
$> /usr/bin/git submodule foreach --recursive git config --local --name-only --get-regexp 'http\.https\:\/\/github\.com\/\.extraheader' && git config --local --unset-all 'http.https://github.com/.extraheader' || :
```

What do those `git` commands do and why do they run after a GitHub Action Workflow completes? Since the GitHub Action executes in a container or VM I thought it could simply be "town down" at the end without requiring explicit cleanup.

I am just curious about the what and the why behind this bit of code that runs every time my GitHub Action executes.

Comment: It's a cleaning step. It cleans the agent git current configuration.. Just check all the git config --global --unset-all instructions

Comment: This is the default `post` step of an action, to cleanup was has been done during the action execution. This `post step` can also be configured in your actions if you want to do something different: [Reference 1](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/creating-actions/metadata-syntax-for-github-actions#post) & [Reference 2](https://github.com/actions/runner/blob/e0643c694cda4e0576b67cbf5247a0cb8dfe391b/docs/adrs/0361-wrapper-action.md)